# SharePoint App , task creation won't sent assignment email

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I'm trying to send an assignment email when a task is created . To my understanding this should happen automatically but it doesn't work for me.

Any ideas why it doesn't work ? If i try to sent email through the workflow it works but not when a task is assigned to a user

Comment: Try to verify if the worklfow was canceled or completed, also try to verify your worklfow history.

Answer (score 1):

As a first point you have to validate that the outgoing mail service in SharePoint is enabled: 
Central Administration--> System settings--> e-mail and text messages (SMS)--> Configure outgoing e-mail settings The fields you must take care of the Following form:

Outbound SMTP server: This field specifies the Relay server (exchange Onpremise) By this server you must allow the sending of mails anonymously.
From Address: Email is specified from where emails are sent.
Repy to address: Email is specified from where emails are sent.
Character set: In this field you specify the number of characters and the format you have, usually this field is left by default.

Note: It is important that the SharePoint FrontEnd server has mail-sending permissions on the Exchange Relay service.

[image]